# Collision detection (Cocos-2d) won't work

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I recently bought the book Learn Cocos 2d 2, and have been following the tutorial on how to make my first game(chapter 4). Basically, what is supposed to happen in the game where I am in the book, you are the alien, and you have to tilt to avoid falling spiders. If you hit one, the game resets.

The probelem I'm having is that the collision detecting doesn't work. The spiders fall and pass through me, the game doesn't reset. As far as I can tell (I just started), it should work, and I couldn't find any differences between the book and this.

This is the code(It's actually an exaple of the game without collisions, and I added the code the book told me to)

http://pastebin.com/0Jt9PdMy

As far as I know(not much), it should work.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would need to stop the spiders actions in that reset loop:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < numSpiders; i++)
            {
                    CCSprite* spider = [spiders objectAtIndex:i];
                    [spider stopAllActions]; // add this
                    spider.position = CGPointMake(imageSize.width * i + imageSize.width * 0.5f, screenSize.height + imageSize.height);
            }
```

Comment: What it is supposed to do is just reset the spiders back to right above the screen.

Comment: If you add the stopAllActions like I show above, that's exactly what will happen. Since the scheduled function is never told to permanently stop, the spiders will reset to the top, and start falling again.